# phonegap barcode scanner not scanning pdf417 bar code

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap, pdf417

I am trying to scan pdf417 barcode, using this https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner repository.My main aim is to scan US driver's license and get whole detail of it,but it always show wrong result and different format UPC_E, EAN_8 even when i scan pdf417 format barcode.I have added format filter as well but it is not working.Anyone who have tried things related to this?

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the barcode scanner plugin does not scan PDF417 unless you add it to the plugin settings.

You have linked to https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner, which is a 4-year old fork from a no-longer mantained plugin, and it lacks the full documentation. In my personal opinion, it's as obsolete as Windows 98.

As you can see at the newer **[phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)**, you have to add **PDF417** to the `formats` list if you want to read those codes.

```
{
    preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
    showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
    showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
    torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
    saveHistory: true, // Android, save scan history (default false)
    prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
    resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500

    /* Add here PDF_417 to support it */
    formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED

    orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
    disableAnimations : true, // iOS
    disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
    disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
}
```

I strongly suggest to use only **official, up-to-date plugins** whenever possible, and if something does not work as expected, report it in the **Issues** section instead of moving to an older fork.

Android 6.0 changed the permission system, and most plugins before that have now become obsolete.